# Não consigo criar zip no Debian

Tags: php, arquivo-zip, linux

Eu não consigo criar um zip no Debian mesmo com a pasta com permissão 777, e o pior é que não retorna erro nenhum.

Código que uso para criar o zip:

```
    function Compress($source_path, $chave)
    {
        // Normaliza o caminho do diretório a ser compactado
        $source_path = realpath($source_path);

        // Caminho com nome completo do arquivo compactado
        // Nesse exemplo, será criado no mesmo diretório de onde está executando o script
        $zip_file = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave.'.zip';

        // Inicializa o objeto ZipArchive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

        // Iterador de diretório recursivo
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source_path),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
            // Pula os diretórios. O motivo é que serão inclusos automaticamente
            if (!$file->isDir()) {
                // Obtém o caminho normalizado da iteração corrente
                $file_path = $file->getRealPath();

                // Obtém o caminho relativo do mesmo.
                $relative_path = substr($file_path, strlen($source_path) + 1);

                // Adiciona-o ao objeto para compressão
                $zip->addFile($file_path, $relative_path);
            }
        }

        // Fecha o objeto. Necessário para gerar o arquivo zip final.
        $zip->close();

        // Retorna o caminho completo do arquivo gerado
        return $zip_file;
    }
```

Comment: mas gera o zip no final? mesmo vazio?

Comment: @h3nr1ke Não, além de não gerar, todo código abaixo de `Compress` não é executado.

Comment: estranho, tem certeza que a chamada para `Compress($source_path, $chave)` está sendo executada, certo? se vc jogar um `echo` dentro logo no começo, ele é visualizado?

Comment: Sim, eu faço um query antes e funciona(além de todo código que tem antes), porem quando vai depois ele não funciona.

Comment: uma coisa que tive de fazer para funcionar foi instalar o `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip` e reiniciar o php `service php7.0-fpm restart` para funcionar certinho... mas fora isso de boas... fiz o teste no Ubuntu (Debian-like)

Answer (score 0):

eu fiz um pequeno ajustes para pegar o diretório e funcionou normalmente seu código, a nao ser que sua variavel esteja vazia ou com um caminho errado que está salvando o arquivo num pasta diferente da qual vc espera

criei o arquivo zip.php

```
<?php
function Compress($source_path, $chave)
{
    // Normaliza o caminho do diretório a ser compactado
    $source_path = realpath($source_path);

    // Caminho com nome completo do arquivo compactado
    // Nesse exemplo, será criado no mesmo diretório de onde está executando o script
    //$zip_file = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave.'.zip';

    /**
     * essa foi a parte que ajustei, trocar sua CONSTANTE pelo caminho atual do arquivo
     */
    $zip_file = getcwd( )."/".$chave.'.zip';

    // Inicializa o objeto ZipArchive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // Iterador de diretório recursivo
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source_path),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {

        // Pula os diretórios. O motivo é que serão inclusos automaticamente
        if (!$file->isDir()) {
            // Obtém o caminho normalizado da iteração corrente
            $file_path = $file->getRealPath();
            // Obtém o caminho relativo do mesmo.
            $relative_path = substr($file_path, strlen($source_path) + 1);

            // Adiciona-o ao objeto para compressão
            $zip->addFile($file_path, $relative_path);
        }
    }
    // Fecha o objeto. Necessário para gerar o arquivo zip final.
    $zip->close();

    // Retorna o caminho completo do arquivo gerado
    return $zip_file;

}
```

no ambiente de teste, criei um pasta chamada **teste** no mesmo nível do arquivo php e executei

```
Compress("teste", "asdfgh");
```

o resultado foi o arquivo  asdfgh.zip no mesmo nível do script php com os arquivos que estavam dentro da pasta